# Animation with different objects moving together?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I have an object who has multiple parts with different modifiers. I don't want to apply the modifiers.

Is there a possibility to connect the the different parts, so that when I animate the whole object, the small ones move automatically along?

Comment: Please show more care of content and spelling in your question and future questions .

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself
Yu  have to select the diffrent objects and go to  Physics
Then press the connect button and select fixed (under Type)

Comment: This means that you even didn't bother to mention that you are doing SIMULATION, not ANIMATION.